# python-redmineでuserをfilterを利用したときの戻り値について

Tags: python, python3, redmine

現在、以下のバージョン、ライブラリを利用してRedmineのActiveなユーザ情報を全て取得しようとしています。

- Python3.7
- python-redmine

対象のRedmineには一度のAPIで取得できる件数(100)を超えているのでページングするために、一度total_countを取得しようと以下のコードを書いてみたのですが、「user_list.total_count」を取得する際に `exceptions.ResultSetTotalCountError` が発生してしまいます。

```py
redmine = Redmine('https://example.com/redmine', key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
user_list = redmine.user.filter(offset=1, limit=1, status=1)

repeat = user_list.total_count // 100
        if user_list.total_count % 100 > 0:
            repeat += 1
        for i in range(0, repeat):
            offset = (i * 100 ) + 1
            user_list = redmine.user.filter(offset=offset, limit=100, status=1)
```

そこで試しにuser_listが取得できてきないのかどうか、上記コードの1行目と2行目の間に以下のコードを追加すると、何の問題もなく正常に動作してしまいました。

```
for user in user_list:
     print(user)
```

なぜこれを追加するだけでうまくいってしまうのか理解できず、、for文を消してsleepを入れてみたり色々と試してみたのですが、原因がわからず気持ち悪いと感じております。

何か思い当たる方いらっしゃれば、Adviseいただけますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [python-redmine/resultsets.py](https://github.com/maxtepkeev/python-redmine/blob/master/redminelib/resultsets.py#L35) に、`"this is known only after ResourceSet evaluation."` と書かれています。`for user in user_list: print(user)` でも良いのでしょうが、例えば `list(user_list)` などとしないと `total_count` がセットされない様です。もしくは、コードにある様に `repeat = len(user_list)` としても良いかと思います。

Comment: @metropolis さん
ご返信ありがとうございます。

`list(user_list)`などとするというのは具体的にどのような方法ですか？
redmine.user.filterの戻り値を`list(user_list)`とはできなかったので、どのように設定するか教えていただけますか？

またlenではただしい値を取得できませんでした。
仮にlistで取得できたとしても、取得するlistの長さはlimitで1と指定しているため、1しか取得できないのではないかと思っています。

total_countはlimitやOffsetにかかわらない、全量を返してくれるためそれを元に繰り返しの回数を決定する処理を書いて(いるつもりで)います。